# glossaries-extra not displaying page numbers

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries-extra

This is my first time with glossaries. I want a symbols list with references to the page where the symbol appears (like in the basic examples!), but for some reason I cannot make the references appear. After reading some manuals and questions here, I have added some options and I'm trying with `glossaries-extra`. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use,automake,xindy]{glossaries-extra}
\makeindex
\makeglossaries
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={an angle}]{al}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}



\begin{document}
\gls{al}

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,title={Symbols List}]

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:
[image]

but I want to add the page number where the symbol `\alpha` in red occurs.

I have tried the following compilation:

```
pdflatex foo
makeindex -s foo.ist -o foo.gls foo.glo
pdflatex foo
```

and overleaf compilation.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\printunsrtglossary` doesn't show the numbers unless you use it with `bib2gls`. (See [glossaries-extra and bib2gls: An
Introductory Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls-begin.pdf).) If you want to use `makeindex` then you need to use `\printglossary` instead. However, you've actually used the `xindy` package option, which means the associated files need to be processed using `xindy` instead of `makeindex`. With `sort=use`, there's no particular benefit in using `xindy` instead of `makeindex`, so you can remove that package option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={an angle}]{al}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}    

\begin{document}
\gls{al}

\printglossary[type=symbols,title={Symbols List}]

\end{document}
```

The `symbols` glossary doesn't use the `.glo` and `.gls` extensions, so your `makeindex` call won't generate the appropriate files. However, the `automake` option should run `makeindex` using the shell escape.

If you prefer to use the helper `makeglossaries` script (or `makeglossaries-lite`) to run `makeindex` or `xindy` according to the document setup, see [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries) for help incorporating it into your build process.